# Angular : add a fixed search barch to a mat-select dropdown

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using a **mat-select** widget (of Angular-Material) in my app

I'm implementing a search bar **at the top of the select drowpdown** to filter options:

```
 <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner la boutique"
             id="libelleShop">
      <div id="custom-search-input" class="m-1 navbar-fixed-top">
         <input #shopKeyword matInput placeholder="Search"  class="search-input" (keyup)="filterShopsByLibelle(shopKeyword.value)">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
             </button>
       </span>
      </div>

      <mat-option *ngFor="let shop of bad3ShopsListSortedByName"
                          [value]="shop.edoId">
            {{shop.storeName}}
      </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

My purpose is how to keep the search Bard div (#custom-search-input) fixed on the top.

I've tried `position: fixed` but it seems to not work

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: better to use auto-complete of material with filter:https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: 1. fixed top to what? 2.show us your css if you have

Comment: i am stuck with same problem... its not working at all ... i donno how ngx-select-search package owner implemented it.. i looked sourcecode but still not working

Answer (score 3):

> Solution 1

```
<mat-select-search [formControl]="formControlName"></mat-select-search>
```

Add this tag inside mat-select and follow the steps in app.component.ts of [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

> Solution 2

You can use [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) of Angular material

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Answer (score 1):

Make the css(custom-search-input) value as

```
.custom-search-input
{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

This solution worked for me